# Would formatting my MacBook Pro screw things up with git?

Tags: git, macos

I've decided to back up my data and format my MacBook pro back to its factory settings but before I do that, I'm wondering whether would this cause any conflicts with `git` or *GitHub*?

I'm new to version control and all I have is few repositories with exercises from my programming courses.

Should I be saving any special configurations or anything?
Once wiped clean, will there be different procedures to making repositories from my directories?

Comment: A system restore ought have no effect on git behaviour at all.

Comment: as long as you don't forget your id and password on github i don't see any problem, you'll be able to clone again all your repos

Comment: Of course, any local git repo not pushed to a remote repo would be lost.

Comment: @VonC Exactly! You beat me to it by 2 seconds!

Comment: Consider right-clicking on any folder with important stuff and making a compressed archive and then copying the zipped file to a USB stick.

Comment: Thanks. I will def push just in case I've added or edited any additional files. Good thing @Mark Setchell, I plan to backup too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't have any effect on the remote repos (like the ones on GitHub)

That will delete any local settings that you might have.
See `git config --global --list`

Of course, make sure your local repos are pushed to a *remote* repo (like the ones on GitHub) *before* deleting everything.

You might want to or restore after reset at least your username and email.
(`git config user.name`/`git config user.email`): the email has an effect on the gravatar used by GitHub to represents the author of each commit.

Also you will have to [cache again your GitHub credentials](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/).

Comment: *"... pushed to a **remote** repo..."* surely?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the root of a repository under `git` control contains a hidden directory `.git` where **all the repository specific** data is stored. You can thus copy a repository on, say, a usb drive and use it on another machine without any problems.

There are however some **global `git` configuration files**, like [this part of the documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup) specifies:

> Git comes with a tool called `git config` that lets you get and set configuration variables that control all aspects of how Git looks and operates. These variables can be stored in three different places:
>
> 1. `/etc/gitconfig` file: Contains values for every user on the system and all their repositories. If you pass the option `--system` to `git config`, it reads and writes from this file specifically.
> 2. `~/.gitconfig` or `~/.config/git/config` file: Specific to your user. You can make Git read and write to this file specifically by passing the --global option.
> 3. config file in the Git directory (that is, `.git/config`) of whatever repository you’re currently using: Specific to that single repository.
>
> Each level overrides values in the previous level, so values in .git/config trump those in /etc/gitconfig.

So I suggest you ensure that (1.) and (2.) are safely copied (using a backup) such that your git repositories will not - all of a sudden - behave a bit different. It is possible that these files don't even exist if you did not configured these.

Furthermore as @VonC says in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34704511/67579), you should evidently back up your credentials (login and password or an `ssh` key you have generated). However this applies to backup in general: make sure that your logins and passwords are safe.

Comment: I haven't configured these but thanks for mentioning. It would be interesting to know what I can do with those global configuration files. I'll have to check that out later on ;)